# How to filter a row based on multiple indexes and multiple conditions?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, filter

I have a file which looks like this:

```
#This is TEST-data
2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00,ID-10,3,London,Manchester,London,1,1,1
2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00,ID-10,3,London,London,Manchester,1,1
2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00,ID-20,2,London,London,1,1
2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00,ID-20,2,London,London1,1
2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00,ID-30,3,Madrid,Sevila,Sevilla,1,1,1
2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00,ID-30,GGG,Madrid,Sevilla,Madrid,1
2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00,ID-40,GGG,Madrid,Barcelona,1,1,1,1
2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00
2020-09-07T00:00:03.230+02:00
```

`Index[2]` in each row shows how much cities are present in that specific row. So the first row has value 3 for `index[2]`, which are `London, Manchester, London.`

I am trying to do the following:

For every row I need to check if any of `row [3]` + the cities mentioned after it (based on the number of cities) are present in `cities_to_filter`. But this only needs to be done if row[2] is a number. I also need to tackle the fact that some rows contain less then 2 items.

This is my code:

```
path = r'c:\data\ELK\Desktop\test_data_countries.txt'

cities_to_filter = ['Sevilla', 'Manchester']

def filter_row(row):
    if row[2].isdigit():
        amount_of_cities = int(row[2]) if len(row) > 2 else True
        
    cities_to_check = row[3:3+amount_of_cities]
    
    condition_1 =  any(city in cities_to_check for city in cities_to_filter)    
    return condition_1

with open (path, 'r') as output_file:
    reader = csv.reader(output_file, delimiter = ',')
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        if filter_row(row):
            print(row)
```

Right now I receive the following error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'condition_1' `referenced before assignment`
```

Comment: @mhawke. This is the question.

Comment: Why are you accessing `row[2]` in the main for loop? Isn't `int(row[2])` supposed to be guarded by the `isdigits()` check in `filter_row()`?  If you want to print `cities_to_check` do it in `filter_row()`. If you do that you will not see that error again. You will. however. see a `NameError` raised from the next line when the non-existent `amount_of_cities` variable is referenced.

Comment: What do you propose to do with those lines that contain `GGG` in `row[2]` where the city count should be? Do you want to ignore those lines, or do you still want to attempt to check whether the cities should be filtered? What about the lines that have only the timestamp? Silently ignore them, dump them to stderr or abort the program?

Comment: @mhawke I solved it. Thank you bro. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm not sure that you have :) `if row[2].isdigit(): amount_of_cities =  int(row[2]) if len(row) > 2 else True`  is mixed up. `len(row)` is guaranteed to be > 2 because the `if` condition has already accessed the 3rd item in the row. Also, setting `amount_of_cities` to `True` is effectively setting it to 1 because `True` is 1 if treated as an int. Check my answer for a suggested solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
import sys

def filter_row(row):
    '''Returns True if the row should be removed'''
    if len(row) > 2:
        if row[2].isdigit():
            amount_of_cities = int(row[2]) 
            cities_to_check = row[3:3+amount_of_cities]
        else:
            # don't have valid city count, just try the rest of the row
            cities_to_check = row[3:]
        return any(city in cities_to_check for city in cities_to_filter)

    print(f'Invalid row: {row}', file=sys.stderr))
    return True

with open (path, 'r') as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter = ',')
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        if filter_row(row):
            print(row)
```

In `filter()` the row length is checked to ensure that a possible city count in `row[2]` is present. If the count is a number it is used to calculate the upper bound to extract the cities to check. Otherwise the row from index 3 to the end of the row is processed which will include the additional number values, but probably not city names.

If there are too few fields the row it is filtered by returning `True` and an error message is printed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to filter before to optimize everything.
Here the beginning of the path you should explore :

```
test_data = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['ID-10','ID-10','ID-20','ID-20','ID-30','ID-30','ID-40'],'id':[3,3,2,2,3,'GGG','GGG'],'cities':[['London','Manchester','London',1,1,1],['London','Manchester','London',1,1],['London','London',1,1],['London','London',1,1],['Madrid','Sevilla','Sevilla',1,1,1],['Madrid','Sevilla','Sevilla',1],['Madrid','Barçelona',1]]})

cities_to_filter = ['Sevilla', 'Manchester']
_condition1 = test_data.index.isin(test_data[test_data.id.str.isnumeric() != False][test_data[test_data.id.str.isnumeric() != False].id > 2].index)
test_data['results'] = np.where( _condition1,1,0)
test_data
```

OUTPUT :

[image]

And then you apply an 'any() in' for filtering the cities, but there are a lot of ways.